# Supporting HTTPS in iOS XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, https, xmpp

I am developing an Chatting app for iOS platform. I am using XMPP framework downloaded from https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.
 Initially server was not having certificates installed, it was a plain **HTTP** service. But now certificate authentication is required because now certificate is installed and need to support  **HTTPS** protocol. I Tried just implementing following method,

`- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveTrust:(SecTrustRef)trust
                                      completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL shouldTrustPeer))completionHandler;`

But now it is not connecting to that server or certificate validation is not happening. 
Any idea apart from above delegate method do we need to set up any other thing ?

To connect to server i am using following method,
`- (BOOL)connectWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout error:(NSError **)errPtr`

Regards,
Bhat

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the above issue by setting the isSecure values as YES.

The following method was not publicly available  for other classes in XMPPStream class.

-(void)setIsSecure:(BOOL)flag

By setting the above value am able to connect the port 5223 and SSL handshake works perfectly..

Regards,
Chandrika